# Fish history not working; more specifically, not adding new entries

Tags: fish

I don't really know exactly since when this happen. I think since I updated to Ubuntu 20.04.

I have used Fish since a long time, and earlier via Linuxbrew to get a more recent version.

So I assume this is some mixup of the configs or formats.

How do I debug this? I don't get any error. When I press up-arrow in a new shell, it will print me some very old entries (I don't remember from when, but some years old I think).

Strangely, even removing `~/.config/fish` did not resolve this. It even still has the old history. I actually have no idea where it gets this history from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, `strace` helped me to debug this. I got already much more information. The only problem with strace is that it is way too verbose. Anyway, via `strace -e file fish`, I saw this:

```
...
stat("/home/az/.local/share/fish/fish_history", 0x7ffd4f2e4160) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/az/.config/fish/fish_history", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
unlink("/home/az/.local/share/fish/fish_history") = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/az/.local/share/fish/fish_history", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
stat("/home/az/.local/share/fish/fish_history", 0x7ffd4f2e4160) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/az/.bash_history", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
...
```

So, first of all, that old `.bash_history` really is the old history I'm seeing.

Also, interesting that there is a `EACCES (Permission denied)` error.

For some reason, in `/home/az/.local/share/`:

```
drwx------  3 root root   4096 Jan 16  2019  fish/
```

I don't really know how I ended up having that.

Anyway, doing `sudo chown az:users /home/az/.local/share/fish` fixed the problem!